# 'struct std::string' has no member named 'c_string'

Tags: c++

I am receiving the error message 'struct std::string' has no member named 'c_string' in my code.  I am basing the structure of this code off of a code in my textbook that successfully wrote a code with my compiler.  What syntax errors could be causing this particular error?  (it's on line 11)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>  
#include<cstdlib>   
#include<string>     
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string payroll = "table.dat";   
    ofstream MyCout;
    MyCout.open(payroll.c_string());

        if (MyCout.fail())
       {
        cout<<"Your file was not found";
        exit(1);
       }
        MyCout<<setiosflags(ios::fixed)
              <<setiosflags(ios::showpoint)
              <<setprecision(2);
        MyCout << "B Caldwell    555-88-2222"<<17.32<<37<<endl
               << "Next Line"<<0.00<<00<<endl;
               << "Next Line"<<0.00<<00<<endl;
        MyCout.close();
        cout<<"The file "<<payroll<<" has been successfully written"<<endl;
       system ("Pause");
       return 0;
       }
```

I'm not sure if this helps or not, but here is the code that I am basing it off of

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream> 
#include<cstdlib>  
#include<string> 
#include<iomanip>   
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    string filename = "prices.dat";   
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(filename.c_str());

 if (outFile.fail())  
    {    
      cout << "The file was not successfully opened" << endl; 
      exit(1);  
     }
outFile << setiosflags(ios::fixed)
        << setiosflags(ios::showpoint) 
        << setprecision(2);

outFile << "Mats " << 39.95 << endl
        << "Bulbs " << 3.22 << endl       
        << "Fuses " << 1.08 << endl;
outFile.close();  
  cout << "The file " << filename << " has been successfully written."<<endl;
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The name of the function is `c_str()`

Comment: You need to look closer at the code you're comparing it off, or use an up-to-date IDE which shows the functions you can use. I'm voting to close a typographical error

Comment: I found the error - I think I was looking over it too fast too many times.  it should be c_str, not c_string.  Sorry for the stupid question but thank you for the useful response.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` has no function or member called `c_string`, hence the exact compiler error. You can find plenty of information online about what members and functions are available to call on standard library objects, for instance [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

If you look closer at the code you're referencing, you'll see you meant to use `c_str()` instead.

Their code:

```
ofstream outFile;
outFile.open(filename.c_str());
```

Your code:

```
ofstream MyCout;
MyCout.open(payroll.c_string());
```

The solution:

```
ofstream MyCout;
MyCout.open(payroll.c_str());
```